# Dirac matrix algebra from bosonic creation/anihilation operators?

Tags: operators, fermions, bosons, dirac-matrices, clifford-algebra

Using some generic *fermionic* creation/anihilation operators $a_i$ and $a_i^{\dagger}$ ($i, j = 1, 2, 3, \dots, N$) such that
\begin{align}
\{ a_i, \, a_j^{\dagger} \} &= \delta_{ij}, \tag{1} \\[1ex]
\{ a_i, \, a_j \} = \{ a_i^{\dagger}, \, a_j^{\dagger} \} &= 0, \tag{2}
\end{align}
it is possible to construct new operators $\gamma_a$ (where $a, b = 1, 2, 3, \dots, 2 N$) that produces a Clifford algebra on an *even* dimensional vector space:
\begin{equation}\tag{3}
\{ \gamma_a, \, \gamma_b \} = 2 \, \delta_{ab}.
\end{equation}
Of course $\{ A, \, B \} \equiv A B + B A$.  For example:
\begin{align}
\gamma_i &= a_i + a_i^{\dagger}, \tag{4} \\[1ex]
\gamma_{n+i} &=-\, i (a_i - a_i^{\dagger}). \tag{5}
\end{align}
For an *odd* dimensional vector space, we could introduce a new $\gamma_{2n + 1}$ by multiplication of all the $\gamma_a$ together:
\begin{equation}\tag{6}
\gamma_{2n + 1} = -\, i^n \, \gamma_1 \, \gamma_2 \, \gamma_3 \cdots \gamma_{2 n},
\end{equation}
such that
\begin{align}
\{ \gamma_{2 n + 1}, \, \gamma_a \} &= 0,
&\{ \gamma_{2 n + 1}, \, \gamma_{2 n + 1} \} = 2.
\end{align}
It is also well known that using a **pair** of *bosonic* creation/anihilation operators $b_1$, $b_1^{\dagger}$, $b_2$, $b_2^{\dagger}$ combined with the three Pauli matrices, we could reproduce the whole angular momentum theory of quantum mechanics.

Now, I'm wondering if it's possible to built the same Clifford algebra (3) with a generic set of *bosonic* operators $b_i$, $b_i^{\dagger}$ (where $i, j = 1, 2, 3, \dots, N$) such that
\begin{align}
[ b_i, \, b_j^{\dagger} ] &= \delta_{ij}, \tag{7} \\[1ex]
[ b_i, \, b_j ] = [ b_i^{\dagger}, \, b_j^{\dagger} ] &= 0. \tag{8}
\end{align}
So is there some special combination of the $b_i$, $b_i^{\dagger}$ (analogous to (4), (5), maybe non-linear) that could reproduce (3)?

Comment: [Jordan-Wigner transformation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jordan%E2%80%93Wigner_transformation)?