# Is there an identity for anti-commutator $\{ A B, \, C D \}$ in terms of commutators $[\, , \,]$ only?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, commutator, clifford-algebra, anticommutator

I'm looking for an identity that could express the anti-commutator
$$\tag{1}
\{ A B , \, C D \} \equiv A B C D + C D A B
$$
expressed as a combination of commutators only: $[A,\, C]$, $[A, \, D]$, etc.

Is there such an identity?  I suspect there is none.

I'm thinking of something similar to the following identity (with only commutators on the right side, no anti-commutators):
$$\tag{2}
[A B, \, C D] = A C \, [B, \, D] + A \, [B, \, C] \, D + C \, [A, \, D] \, B + [A, \, C] \, D B.
$$

---

**EDIT:** I'm more specifically interested in evaluating the following:
$$\tag{3}\{ a_i^{\dagger} \, a_j, \, a_k^{\dagger} \, a_l \},$$
where $a_i$ and $a_i^{\dagger}$ are *bosonic* operators satisfying
\begin{align}
[ a_i, \, a_j^{\dagger}] &= \delta_{ij}, \tag{4}\\[1ex]
[a_i, \, a_j] = [a_i^{\dagger}, \, a_j^{\dagger}] &= 0. \tag{5}
\end{align}

Comment: Are the operators Grassmann-even?

Comment: @Qmechanic, the operators $A$, $B$, $C$ $D$ are general boson operators (creation and anhiliation $a_i$, $a_i^{\dagger}$).

Comment: Your (2) has products over and above commutators. That is the sort of thing you want?

Comment: @CosmasZachos, yes, the identity I'm looking could have some operators around the commutators.  I don't care of the way they are distributed, I only need commutators on the right hand part, no anti-commutators.

Answer (score 7):

Let me put on my math hat by providing a counterexample:

Let's say
$$
A = a_1, \\B= a_2, \\C= a_3, \\D = a_4
$$
where $a_i$ are regular bosonic anhiliation operators, therefore
$$
[a_i, a_j] \equiv 0
$$

If OP's proposition works:
$$
\{ A B , \, C D \} \equiv A B C D + C D A B = 2a_1a_2a_3a_4
$$
will be reduced to zero, since any combination of 
$[a_i, a_j] $
is zero. But $2a_1a_2a_3a_4$ is evidently not identical to zero.

Thus there is no such construct.

Comment: This answer is interesting.  Actually, my operators $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ are combinations of boson operators $a_i$ and $a_i^{\dagger}$.  I'm wondering about the anti-commutator $\{ a_i^{\dagger} \, a_j, \, a_k^{\dagger} \, a_l \}$.

Comment: @Cham, can you shed some light on the motivation of the said anti-commutator? It might help elicit a satisfactory resolution.

Comment: I'm trying to see if we could generate a Clifford algebra from boson operators only, like we could generate the same Clifford algebra from fermonic operators $a$ and $a^{\dagger}$ (which is truly fascinating!).  See this topic : https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/535230/dirac-matrix-algebra-from-bosonic-creation-anihilation-operators?noredirect=1#comment1211161_535230

Comment: @Cham oic, as pointed out by AccidentalFourierTransform, Jordan–Wigner transformation will do, with the caveat that its generalization to non-1D case is bit hairy notwithstanding the wiki claim.

Comment: @Cham, if you broaden your definition of Clifford algebra, there is actually a suitable mathematical apparatus. Search for "symplectic clifford algebra", you will be amazed that there is a decent body of literature devoted to the topic.

Answer (score 4):

Since for any commutator
$$
[A,B] = \{A,B\} -2BA,
$$
we can get rid of the anticommutator easily:
$$
\{AB,CD\} = [AB,CD]+CDAB.
$$
Then, one can use identity
$$
[AB,CD] = A[B,C]D + [A,C]BD + CA[B,D] + C[A,D]B,
$$
and then the expression contains only commutators and an extra $CDAB$-term.